# How to setup breeze on azure, check if the breezecontroller is running

Tags: azure, breeze

I am using hottowel angular with breeze and EF6. On my local machine it works fine in dev and release. I have configured and deployed to  an Azure website and it starts but on the first query I get the following error in chrome

GET ...cloudapp.net/breeze/Breeze/Metadata 500 (Internal Server Error) angular.js:7997
ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at _queryFailed ....cloudapp.net/app/services/datacontext.js:51:23)
    at wrappedErrback (....cloudapp.net/scripts/angular.js:10958:78)

The request is fomulated correctly, website/breeze/Breeze/MetaData meaning that at least BreezeWebApiConfig.cs is getting loaded and I have manually entered the http in a browser and I still get the 500 error. How can I check if the breezecontroller is runnung?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did a debug release and ran the website again and in IE I saw the following stacktrace which tells me that EF was failing to setup. The issue is that EF must be added to the web application, even though it is the dataaccess project (in my case) that actually connects to the db using EF. So I did this and the problem is solved, well now I have a timeout issue connecting to the db but onwards and upwards.

{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.","ExceptionType":"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.d_*1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d*_0.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"$id":"2","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(String providerTypeName, String providerInvariantName)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b_*2(ProviderElement e)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b*_1()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DbProviderServices()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)\r\n   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)\r\n   at KC.Data.Context..ctor() in c:\Users\grammie\Source\Repos\kcsec\KCData\Context.cs:line 52"}}